# HangFire migration from service

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire, hangfire-sql

In my application (C# api dotnet 5 modified to run as windows service) I use HangFire. When running my application in debug mode from Visual Studio, all works fine, and my database is being created including HangFire tables when I invoke migrations.

When I pack it up and try and install it as a service, the database gets created, but without the HangFire tables. I have tried everything I can think of, but without luck.

Anybody out there that know the requirements to make HangFire migrate from inside a windows service?

From Main

```
                var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(config =>
                {
                    config.UseKestrel(options =>
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(Configuration["port"]),
                            listenOptions =>
                            {
                                listenOptions.UseHttps("generated.pfx", "xxxxx");
                            })).UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot);
                    config.UseIISIntegration();
                    config.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((buildercontext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
                .Configure(new TMConfiguration
                {
                    EnableLogging = true,
                    EnableTracing = true,
                    UseAutoMapper = false,
                    UseHealthCheck = true,
                    EnableSwagger = false,
                    ProductName = "TM Backend Server"
                })
                .Build();
```

From ConfigureServices (startup)

```
        // running migrate and applying all migrations
        context.Database.Migrate();

            //adding support for Hangfire in the Db
        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true,
                EnableHeavyMigrations = true,
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true
            })
        );

        services.AddHangfireServer(action =>
        {
            action.ServerName = $"{Environment.MachineName}:default";
            action.Queues = new[] { "default" };
            action.WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 5;
        });

        services.AddHangfireServer(action =>
        {
            action.ServerName = $"{Environment.MachineName}:serial";
            action.Queues = new[] { "serial" };
            action.WorkerCount = 1;
        });
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Not too easy, but working on it. In the meantime, I have added  the most important parts from startup.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around to sharing my findings. It was all due to privileges on the SQL Server side. A lot of work to figure out how to setup a login and assign the needed privileges and not too much :-). If anybody runs into something similar, comment here, and I will be happy to share my findings.